# Resolving node & pm2 based nodejs setup in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nodes, pm2

When I'm running my nodejs using the command "node server.js", I'm able to run the API server effectively. 
But when I'm running the sever using the command "pm2 start server.js --name server -i max", its restarting mt server continously and throwing below error in the logs (I'm using "pm2 log" command to view the logs)

```
0|server  | Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000
0|server  |     at listenOnMasterHandle (net.js:1347:16)
0|server  |     at rr (internal/cluster/child.js:126:12)
0|server  |     at Worker.send (internal/cluster/child.js:93:7)
0|server  |     at process.onInternalMessage (internal/cluster/utils.js:45:8)
0|server  |     at process.emit (events.js:203:15)
0|server  |     at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
0|server  |     at emit (internal/child_process.js:832:12)
0|server  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
PM2       | App name:server id:0 disconnected
PM2       | App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2       | App [server:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2       | App [server:0] online
```

I made sure that no other node based service is running in my Ubuntu machine.

*I just noticed that in the latest versoin of **"Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type" its not working**. But its working good in Ubuntu Server 18.04 without any problem*

Comment: Can you see what is running on port 3000 when you run the pm2 command with this?
`lsof -i :80`

Comment: I guess the problem is that your nodeJS app and pm2 try to run on the same port, can you try to run it with this command?
`pm2 start server.js -- --name server --port 1520 --instances 1`

Comment: @TasosBu Nothing is running on port 3000. Even the above command with port 1520 is throwing same error

Comment: If you change your nodeJS port will it throw the same error with the updated port?

Comment: PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online
PM2      | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [server:0] online